# Django Rest Framework UniqueValidator throw error when update an item with old data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer class:

```
class AdministratorCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Administrator
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
        ]
    username = serializers.CharField(
        source='user.username',
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        source='user.email',
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(
        source='user.password',
        allow_blank=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )
    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        source='user.first_name'
    )
    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        source='user.last_name'
    )
```

When I create new administrator, the validator of username and email work well.

But when I update data. I just simple fill old data and save, but the validator say that username and email must be unique.

How can I change this validator only execute when updating with new value that not equal the old one?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before. I fixed it by overriding the `update()` method on the serializer and using the `exclude()` method for Django queryset:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    username = validated_data.get('username', '')

    if User.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk).filter(username=username):
        raise serializers.ValidationError('User with this username already exists.')

    instance.__dict__.update(**validated_data)
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

Now it only raises error if any other user tries to update his username, that is the same as yours.

Hope this will help :)

*UPDATE*:

You can override the `validate_<property>()` method. In your case:

```
def validate_username(self, value):
    # self.instance is the current instance (Administrator)
    # this method is called on every request, so you should do
    # if self.instance
    # to check if the method is update/post, so you can have an instance
    # and then you do the check for the username uniqueness
    if self.instance and User.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(username=value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError('User with this username already exists.')

    return value
```